# Cant Download anything

Tags: package-management, system

I am currently on ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to download steam launcher but when I try I get a screen that reads.

```
"The package system is broken
 Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f"
```

and when I open details it reads.

```
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:

linux-image-extra-3.13.0-73-generic: Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-73-generic but it is not installed
linux-image-generic: Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-73-generic but it is not installed"
```

Please Help Thank You.

```
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                914M  4.0K  914M   1% /dev
tmpfs                               185M  940K  184M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--kylin--vg-root  292G   43G  235G  16% /
none                                4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                924M  184K  924M   1% /run/shm
none                                100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                           236M  236M     0 100% /boot
izzy-22@Randys-PC:~$
```

Comment: Please run the following: `sudo apt-get install -f`, then `sudo apt-get update`, and finally `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Command option 'f' is not known. sorry im probably doing somethig wron and im not understanding

Comment: i also have a red circle with a white line wheremy updates useto be but it wont letme downlead it as well

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Looking at your error messages your are supposed to run `sudo apt-get install -f` first then run then other ones I gave

Comment: Please post an image of that circle so I can relate to what your saying

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn4ZC.jpg

Comment: Ok, just ignore that it's there because your system needs certain updates

Comment: If the first command didn't run, run the other two and lets see

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeZRZ.png

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAqVk.png

Comment: the upgrade command seemed to be working until it gave the that

Comment: Your disk seems to be full, pls run `sudo df -h` and paste in your question

Comment: i put the results in my question

Comment: `/boot` dir is full  and needs to be clean of junk

Comment: pls run `ls /boot` and post

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that some of your packages depend on other ones and this is causing `apt` to get stuck. I'd say open terminal and run `sudo apt install linux-image-3.13.0.73-generic`, because that package is not installed and seems to be the cause of the problems. Just install that package and then report back whether it worked. It should resolve that dependency error.

Now looking at edits in the question, your /boot is full, so try running,

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

to remove old kernels and initrds stored there. Then run

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0.73-generic`.

This should fix the dependency problems

Comment: No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-73-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-73-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-73-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-73-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-73-generi_3.13.0-73.116_i386.deb

Comment: its saying i have no space but iknow i have plenty

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe your `/boot` partition is full. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot

Comment: @JanKarlosQuirindongo can you post the output of `lsblk` in the question?